# Why do bash's man pages have double letters when written to file?

Tags: bash, manpage

I've been wondering about this for a while. Whenever I run a command of the form "man [command] >> file.txt", there's a weird phenomenon where words that were bold when I viewed the man page in Terminal appear in the text file with each letter repeated twice.

For example,

**DESCRIPTION**

The **find** utility recursively descends the directory tree for each path listed

turns into

DDEESSCCRRIIPPTTIIOONN

The ffiinndd utility recursively descends the directory tree for each path
listed

Why is this? I can't think of a file encoding for which this makes sense. (If it encoded "bold" as "write each letter twice", then the band Abba would show up as A **b** a, among other problems...)

Comment: Which system are you on?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at that file with `od`, `hexdump` or something similar - I bet there are characters in between the "double" letters. Some old terminals implemented bold by a backspace and overprint method... You'll find similar oddities where there is underlining, which was usually implemented by a letter-backspace-underline sequence...

Comment: It's a formatting quirk when viewing the file as raw text, use `$ man <filename>` to read the file and view correctly. Example, on a Mac  `$ man /usr/share/doc/postfix/SQLITE_README`

Answer (score 3):

Try `man -7` or `man --ascii [command] >> file.txt` which will export man pages to ascii.